# The autoinstall option is ignored

Tags: system-installation, pxe

The autoinstall option is being ignored.
My grub.cfg is as below. The VM being installed makes no attempt to retrieve the user-data and meta-data files from the web server.

Where is the documentation that explains what boot options you can put in to the grub.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

> "Where is the documentation that explains what boot options you can
>   put in to the grub.cfg?"

You can find the docs for GRUB in a few formats [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/), look for the sections [15](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Environment) and [16](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Commands).